# Automatically created MainActivity has errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have just started with Java and Android programming and Eclipse created this MainAcitivity for me:

```
package com.dummies.android.lautlosmodus;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

But i can`t run it because of this error:

"R cannot be resolved to a variable"

Anyone got an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Eclipse is no longer officially supported. Use Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Add `import com.dummies.android.lautlosmodus.R;`
Also, use AppCompatActivity as extended class. ActionBarActivity is deprecated.

Comment: Please explain how to do this exactly.

Comment: Then try  Project-> Clean

Comment: Also, make sure you don't import this `import android.R;`

Comment: Still the same problem here.

Comment: Can you post your manifest file? It's called AndroidManifest.xml . Should be in your project files.

Answer (score 0):

Try Android Studio or alternate is to clean your project.
Project->Clean.